# Grails 3.3 How do I reduce console output?

Tags: grails

When running the application in the development environment, the console window fills up with constant messages like "85% Executing....".

This makes finding log statements from my application difficult.

How can I turn these off? I have no idea what "package" is generating this stuff.

Comment: Can you paste son example logs?

Comment: You can use log4j for logging your applications log separately and that also helps in your application performance as the are asynchronous.

Answer (score 0):

If you are in IntelliJ, use the bootRun task instead of the Grails task. Currently output is broken.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-178879

If not please provide what terminal it is. It is expected to show the 85% Executing as the task is still executing, but should not append to the terminal.